lombok @SuperBuilder changing one of my field names?
I have a hierarchy of DTO classes created by lombok @SuperBuilder. When using it, one of the fields becomes mysteriously renamed. Why is that and what can I do to maintain the original name ?  Is this a lombok problem or feature - but I cannot find any hints in the lombok docs?
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExpenseDto {
    @NonNull
    @Size(max = 30)
    protected String recipient;

    @NonNull
    @Size(max = 30)
    protected String purpose;
    
    // ...

    protected boolean isInvoiced;  // this somehow is changed
}


@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
public class ExpenseEntityDto extends ExpenseDto {
    @Size(max = 16)
    long expenseId;

    @Size(max = 16)
    @NonNull
    protected String accountNo;

    // ...
}


I use it like so:
public ExpenseEntityDto domainToEntityDto(Expense domain) {
   return ExpenseEntityDto.builder()
                .expenseId(domain.getExpenseId())
                .accountNo(domain.getAccountNo())
                .recipient(domain.getRecipient())
                .purpose(domain.getPurpose())
                .isInvoiced(domain.isInvoiced())  // produces a field 'invoiced' !?
                .build();
}

In flight, the DTO JSON looks like this:
{
    "recipient": "Mobsters Inc.",
    "purpose": "protection services rendered",
    "expenseId": 1,
    "accountNo": "1234",
    "invoiced": false     // Huh !? expected 'isInvoiced' instead
}

Even better, the openapi spec (generated from smallrye-openapi extension in quarkus) shows BOTH versions in the Schema (same in swagger ui):
ExpenseEntityDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        recipient:
          maxLength: 30
          type: string
        purpose:
          maxLength: 30
          type: string
        isInvoiced:
          type: boolean
        invoiced:
          type: boolean
        expenseId:
          format: int64
          type: integer
        accountNo:
          maxLength: 16
          type: string


You did ofcourse read the documentation?

For boolean fields that start with is immediately followed by a title-case letter, nothing is prefixed to generate the getter name.

This is default Lombok behavior (and not sure if that is overridable). Lombok follows the Java Beans spec as close as possible. A boolean field named isInvoiced would get an accessor like isIsInvoiced which is confusing, hence it doesn't generate an additional is.
Looking at the Java Bean specification all fields will be prefixed with get or set depending on the type. With one exception that is boolean that instead of get will be prefixed with is.
To get an getIsInvoiced you would need to make the field a Boolean field instead of a boolean.
Another option is to add Jackson annotations to force the field in JSON to be isInvoiced (adding a @JsonProperty("isInvoiced") to the field should take care of that.

If that open API extension respects Jackson, OP could try this: @JsonProperty("isInvoiced") boolean invoiced;  so lombok will generate the expected isInvoiced method and the extension will (hopefully) generate the field as isInvoiced.  (Or maybe that extension provides its own config annotations.)

Excellent, I really did overlook that line, Thank you so much. I personally don't see how this is less confusing than just generating a getIsInvoiced() method, but if that is the way the bean gods have made the world - no prob.

@AndrewS: almost - with your approach lombok produces invoiced() method and the JSON field becomes isInvoiced. This also is the only field now showing up in swagger and openapi. Perfect. Thank you all.

@onouv If It was up to us, that whole is malarkey wouldn't exist at all, but, it was 'beanspec' and we wanted to follow some sort of official thing, and changing it now would cause a ton of headache. In other words, the decision made sense at the time, and 'sticking with how it works' is the right answer ever since then, because any benefit obtained by going to something saner (i.e. even if some alternative way would be 'better') is dwarfed by the pain of breaking compatibility. SOURCE: I'm a Lombok maintainer... and partly made that decision at the time, over 10 years ago.
